# Drupal shows "node_form_validate() undefined" error while trying to create a poll

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 website and would like to add a poll to it. I have enabled a Poll module and opened Add material -> Poll page. When I pressed "add variant" button I got an error stating that

```
AJAX HTTP error.
HTTP response code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
Text status: OK
ResponseText: 
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function node_form_validate() in /*/public_html/includes/form.inc on line 1390
```

How can it be fixed? I have rather small experience with Drupal and hardly imagine where to start.

Comment: [My solution to this problem](http://mindwired.blogspot.com/2011/08/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function.html "My solution to this problem")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... Seems I have fixed it myself by adding

```
require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . "/modules/node/node.pages.inc");
```

to /modules/poll/poll.module as described [here](http://drupal.org/node/921398). It turned out this Drupal is not as a terrible CMS.